# CoderByte Array Addition I in Ruby - Difference between working code and non-working code

Tags: arrays, ruby, addition

This is for the Array Addition I question from CoderByte:
Have the function `ArrayAdditionI(arr)` take the array of numbers stored in arr and return the string true if any combination of numbers in the array can be added up to equal the largest number in the array, otherwise return the string false.

For example: if `arr` contains `[4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3]` the output should return true because `4 + 6 + 10 + 3 = 23`. The array will not be empty, will not contain all the same elements, and may contain negative numbers.

I'm wondering why this works:

```
def ArrayAdditionI(arr)
  sum = []
  largest = arr.sort!.pop
  1.upto(arr.count) do |i|
    arr.combination(i).to_a.each do |subarr|
      sum << subarr.inject(:+)
    end
  end

  sum.include?(largest)
end
```

but this won't:

```
def ArrayAdditionI(arr)
  1.upto(arr.count) do |i|
      arr.combination(i).to_a.each do |subarr|
      return true if arr.sort!.last == subarr.inject(:+)
    end
  end

  false
end
```

or why this won't:

```
def ArrayAdditionI(arr)
  sorted_arr = arr.sort
  1.upto(arr.count) do |i|
    arr.combination(i).to_a.each do |subarr|
      return true if  sorted_arr.last == subarr.inject(:+)
    end
  end

  false
end
```

Some key points and difference between the code that I'd like to highlight. In the code that works, an empty array is assigned to "sum." And the largest number in the array is assigned the variable, "largest." To check if the largest is equal to any of the sums, the `.include?` method is called. I wanted to try and access the largest interger from within the block by sorting and calling the last interger on the array, but that doesn't seem to work.

I've tried test cases verbally, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with the code. Is there something implicit that I'm just not picking up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one point that's essential, and that's to remove the largest element of the array before doing comparisons.

Note that in the working code, this happens before iteration:

```
largest = arr.sort!.pop
```

pop is a destructive method; it will change the value of `arr`.

In your attempts, the result will be `true` every time. How do I know? When `i` is 1, `combination(i)` will be an array of length-1 arrays. In effect, every element in the original array is being compared to the maximum. If the maximum element is still included in the array, at some point you will be running:

```
return true if <maximum> == [<maximum>].inject(:+)
```

which will always be true.

Comment: Dam! That helps out a ton! Thanks a bunch @max!